# Create an SQL statement to create columns according to a specific month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to create a SQL code that allows me to create columns according to a specific month, now I have this syntax, but when I run it, it shows me errors. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong ...?

```
alter proc N50_Actualizar_PA
@fecha varchar(6)
as
begin

declare @fin int
declare @cont int
declare @query varchar(5000)
declare @query1 varchar(900)
declare @query2 varchar(900)
declare @query3 varchar(900)

set @fin = (SELECT day(dateadd(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@fecha+'01')+1, 0))))
set @cont = 1
set @query3 = 'while '+@cont+' <= '+@fin+'
begin
set @query = ''S''+cast('+@cont+' as varchar(2))+'' float,E''+cast('+@cont+' as varchar(2))+'' float,''
exec (@query)
set '+@cont+' = '+@cont+' + 1
end'

set @query1 = 'if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name = ''PLANTA_REP_PA_'+@fecha+''')
begin
create table PLANTA_REP_PA_'+@fecha+'(
ITEM int,
UBIGEO varchar(255),
CENTRO_POBLADO varchar(255),
DISTRITO varchar(255),
PROVINCIA varchar(255),
DEPARTAMENTO varchar(255),
TELEFONO varchar(255),
TIPO varchar(255),
OBSERVACION varchar(255),
TECNOLOGIA varchar(255),
ID_VSAT_BTS varchar(255),
UBICACION_VSAT_BTS varchar(255),
NIVEL_SENAL varchar(255),
TIPO_ENERGIA varchar(255),
COMENTARIOS varchar(255),
CANT_LINEAS_B_ARRENDADOR varchar(255),
'+ @query3 +'
TOTAL_SALIENTE float,
TOTAL_ENTRANTE float,
SALIENTE_MOVILES float,
ENTRANTE_MOVILES float)
end
else
begin
truncate table PLANTA_REP_PA_' + @fecha + '
end'

set @query2 = 'INSERT INTO PLANTA_REP_PA_' + @fecha + '
Select * from Temp_Planta_Rep_PA'

exec (@query3)
print (@query1)
print (@query2)

end
```

Comment: post the full text of your errors ...

Comment: This is the error: Mens 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure N50_Actualizar_PA, Line 15 
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'while' to data type int.

Comment: The specific problem (one of at least three I see in the query) is that you're trying to concatenate a text string ('begin set @query = ...' with an integer variable (@cont).  You'd need to cast that to varchar before concatenating.  However, changing that specific issue won't solve your problem, as your general approach to your apparent goal isn't going to work anyway.  Give me a few minutes and I'll see if I can post an answer that will get you pointed in the right direcion.

Comment: Please post a sample of a value passed to the fecha variable, along with the expected columns you're trying to create with @query3

Comment: The fecha variable is like this: '201402', this month have 28 days, so it have to create 56 columns like this: S1,E1,S2,E2,....

Answer (score 1):

**General Problem #1:** this is a poor question.  You got a lot of downvotes here, and they're likely all because your problem and goals weren't clearly laid out, and you didn't provide sufficient information.  If that wasn't bad enough, though, posting "fix my code" problems is hugely frowned on by the community.  [Read this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) before posting next time.

**General Problem #2:** this is a *horrible* idea.  You're creating a table for specific date ranges, you're truncating blindly ... yeah.  Not a good design.  New table every month is poor practice, but that's your business.

**SQL Problem #1:** you're trying to concatenate strings and integers (`set @query3 = 'while '+@cont+' <= '+@fin+' ...`).  You would have to convert those integers to strings before doing that. That doesn't matter, though, because

**SQL Problem #2:** the entire WHILE statement is wrong.  The purpose of the statement is, I assume, to stuff a variable with the names of your columns.  But it isn't doing that.

*SQL Problem #2a* - the WHILE loop isn't concatenating a column list.  Read it again: you're telling SQL to execute @query, which in the best-case scenario will be `S1 float, E1 float,`.  That's not a SQL command.  What you need to do instead is `set @query = @query + 'S1 ...`.  That way, it will build up the string.

*SQL Problem #2b* - the lengths of your variables are wrong.  Trying to stuff a varchar(5000) query into a varchar(900) query isn't going to work.

**SQL Problem #3:** you never attach your column list into the table definition.  Instead, by writing

```
CANT_LINEAS_B_ARRENDADOR varchar(255),
'+ @query3 +'
TOTAL_SALIENTE float,
```

you're telling SQL to set the value to

```
CANT_LINEAS_B_ARRENDADOR varchar(255),
while 1 <= 28 
begin
set ...
TOTAL_SALIENTE float,
```

This will never work.   What you're trying to do is add in the concatenated string theoretically housed in @query, in which case you should write

```
CANT_LINEAS_B_ARRENDADOR varchar(255),
'+ @query +'
TOTAL_SALIENTE float,
```

That still won't solve it, because

**SQL Problem #4:** you haven't executed @query3 yet.  You have to build and set the values for @query before you try to concatenate those values with your table definition. Instead, you need to execute that WHILE loop and populate the values for @query before you concatenate it with @query1.

There are more issues with your methodology and practices, (such as including the TRUNCATE TABLE command in the same block) but I think that gives you the general idea, and, to be frank, I'm not a member of Stack Overflow so I can do your job for you.  I'm here because I like SQL, and figuring out a puzzle is fun ... and I'm here because someone took the time to explain things to me, and if I can help someone out that's my way of paying it forward.

I'm going to post a query below that should get you a lot closer to your goal.  That might be a bad idea, because giving it to you won't force you to read my analysis of your code and make the changes yourself.  Take the time to compare the two, understand the differences and why I made these changes, and go from there.  Chances are, it still needs tweaking, but try to fix it yourself before posting more questions.  If you get an error message, Google it.  If it runs but doesn't do what you expect, pull out the printed code and go through it to figure out why.  [Read this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37308/does-so-discourage-questions-like-this-is-my-code-please-find-the-bug) about asking "fix my code" questions. Good luck!

```
declare @fecha varchar(6)
set @fecha = '201402'

declare @fin int
declare @cont int
declare @query varchar(5000)
declare @query1 varchar(5000)
declare @query2 varchar(900)
declare @query3 varchar(900)

set @fin = (SELECT day(dateadd(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@fecha+'01')+1, 0))))
print @fin


set @cont = 1
set @query = ''
while @cont <= @fin
  begin
    set @query = 
        @query + '
        S' + cast(@cont as varchar(2))+' float, 
        E' + cast(@cont as varchar(2))+' float, '
    set @cont = @cont+ 1
  end

SET @query1 = '
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from sysobjects where name = ''PLANTA_REP_PA_'+@fecha+''')
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE PLANTA_REP_PA_'+@fecha+'
  (
    ITEM int,
    UBIGEO varchar(255),
    CENTRO_POBLADO varchar(255),
    DISTRITO varchar(255),
    PROVINCIA varchar(255),
    DEPARTAMENTO varchar(255),
    TELEFONO varchar(255),
    TIPO varchar(255),
    OBSERVACION varchar(255),
    TECNOLOGIA varchar(255),
    ID_VSAT_BTS varchar(255),
    UBICACION_VSAT_BTS varchar(255),
    NIVEL_SENAL varchar(255),
    TIPO_ENERGIA varchar(255),
    COMENTARIOS varchar(255),
    CANT_LINEAS_B_ARRENDADOR varchar(255),
    '+ @query +'
    TOTAL_SALIENTE float,
    TOTAL_ENTRANTE float,
    SALIENTE_MOVILES float,
    ENTRANTE_MOVILES float
  )
END


TRUNCATE TABLE PLANTA_REP_PA_' + @fecha + '
end'

set @query2 = 'INSERT INTO PLANTA_REP_PA_' + @fecha + '
SELECT * FROM Temp_Planta_Rep_PA'

--exec (@query3)
print @query3
print (@query1)
print (@query2)
```